# Combining LDAP Queries is not giving proper results

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

Good afternoon folks.

I am trying to run an LDAP query against a Domain Controller to include servers with the following requirements:

`OperatingSystem=*server*` (To include all Servers)

OR

`OperatingSystem=*Enterprise*` (To include Windows 10 Machines)

AND

`userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2` (Machine is NOT disabled)

If I run the following, I get what I need for servers:

```
Get-ADObject -searchbase "DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -ldapfilter "(&(objectclass=computer)(operatingSystem=*server*)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))" | Sort-Object Name
```

If I run the following, I get what I need for the Windows 10 Enterprise Boxes:

```
Get-ADObject -searchbase "DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -ldapfilter "(&(objectclass=computer)(operatingSystem=*Enterprise*)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))" | Sort-Object Name
```

However, if I combine like so, I get nothing:

```
Get-ADObject -searchbase "DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -ldapfilter "(&(objectclass=computer)(operatingSystem=*server*)(|(operatingSystem=*Enterprise*))(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))" | Sort-Object Name
```

I have also tried this as well:

```
Get-ADObject -searchbase "DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -ldapfilter "(&(objectclass=computer)(operatingSystem=*server*)(operatingSystem=*Enterprise*)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))" | Sort-Object Name
```

What am I possibly missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second to last filter is almost correct, to make it more readable:

```bash
(&
  (objectclass=computer)
  (|
      (operatingSystem=*server*)
  )
  (operatingSystem=*Enterprise*)  # <- this one should be inside the OR clause
  (!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
)
```

So, the filter should be:

```
(&(objectclass=computer)(|(operatingSystem=*server*)(operatingSystem=*Enterprise*))(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

As you can note, `(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))` can also be simplified to `(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)`. And, if you use `Get-ADComputer` instead of `Get-ADObject`, you can get rid of the `(objectclass=computer)` clause.

Comment: That did it!! So I see what it need. Kinda like this in a sense...

(AND
((Option 1)
(Option 2)
(Option 3))
(OR
((Option 1)
(Option 2)
Option 3))
(NOT
((Option 1)
(Option 2)
(Option 3)).

Comment: The software manufacturer I am using to obtain what I need must utilize the `Get-ADObject` because it automatically populates it and I can't get rid of it. So now, the correct LDAP query that works is: `(&(objectClass=Computer)(|(operatingSystem=*server*)(operatingSystem=*Enterprise*))(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))`